# Spring Security custom FORM_LOGIN_FILTER does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add a custom filter to the spring security configuration. But the problem is that whenever I try to add the filter using xml I am getting an exception saying that

"Configuration problem: Filter beans '< subdomainFilter >' and '< org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#1 >' have the same 'order' value. When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters. Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from  and avoiding the use of < http auto-config='true' >."

I am adding my spring security configuration below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="subdomainFilter" class="com.testbudha.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilterWithSubdomain"/>
    <http pattern="/**" auto-config='false' use-expressions='true'>
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="subdomainFilter" />
        .......
    </http>
    ........
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Spring Security maintains a chain of filters in order to apply its services. The order of the filters is always strictly enforced when using the namespace. When the application context is being created, the filter beans are sorted by the namespace handling code and the standard Spring Security filters each have an alias in the namespace and a well-known position.

Your `<form-login>` is using a filter with alias `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER`. And also you are adding another filter with the same position `(position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="subdomainFilter")`. So you're getting the error message

Try using

```
<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="subdomainFilter" />
```

or

```
<custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="subdomainFilter" />
```

Comment: But my subdomainFilter is capable of handling both. What I want to do is replace the default filter

Comment: You need to disable the `auto-config` option and insert the custom-filter tag to replace the default Spring Security filter in the  position `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER`

Comment: i have turned it off using auto-config='false'. But still I am getting the same result

Comment: Have you define any entry point for your login as you're going to alter the default behavior ?

Comment: Should i?? Because the spring documentation tells that I don't have to add  an entry point

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-custom-filters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89232/discussion-between-rockstar-and-sumodh-krishna).